# Can I keep 100 million records in single table or multiple table?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, rows

We are using SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition. We have 100 million records for 70 countries. My task is to improve the performance of data access from the 100 million records and I need to decide either placing 100 million records in a single table or multiple table. Partitioned Table is not supported in Standard Edition of SQL Server 2008. Which is the best approach either single table or multiple according to best performance in select, insert, delete, update operation from 100 million records. Note: We are doing select, insert, delete, update operation based on the particular country.

Comment: You can partition the single table

Comment: Partitioned Table is not supported in Standard Edition of SQL Server 2008. Any other alternative?

Answer (score 2):

You can partition the single table based on below stategies,

1. Horizontal partitioning : split the table based on columns (which is not applicable in your case)
2. Vertical partitioing : Split the table based on rows (which is helpful in your case)

as you are saying that you are doing operation country wise then probably you can partition table according to country or for a region if no of country count is very high.

That will optimize your queries/operations as comparatively low volume of data will be accessed every time.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but Partition Table is not supported in Standard Edition of SQL Server 2008. Kindly mention alternative to Partition Table in SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition.

Comment: I am not saying partition the table, I am saying split the data into different table based on country name like, 
tablename for USA - USA
tablename for India - India
your queries will be redirected to specific tables (USA, India) which will improve your response time.